# Parallel executions of dynamic URL's coming from for each controller

Tags: jmeter, parallel.foreach

I have a requirement to load the dynamic assets(Images) parallelly which got extracted from the for each loop as there is only one sampler with variable passed. I cant use the parallel controller here, also I don't know the exact number of assets loaded to pass in parallel sampler.

As suggested by you in one of similar issues I have used that approach(add pre sampler) below script and try to execute it in, It is able to pick the values but the child element is always only one(Parallel requests are not happening) however I see the URL's passed main request has  multiple passed.

Pre-Processor script used:

```
String var2 = vars.get("tokens");
String var3 = vars.get("Token");
vars.put("var3", "https://stagingassets.ovid.com"+"/"+var2+"/t/width-150-png?"+var3);
urlsList = vars.get("var3").tokenize(",")
for (int i = 0; i < urlsList.size(); i++) {
def row = new org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty()
row.addItem(urlsList[i])
sampler.data.addItem(row)
log.info("ROWS ${row}")
```

}

variables are coming from CSV where values are saved into a file from each loop using a Flexible File Writer.

please suggest , My requirement is to execute the images parallelly as it happens in the browser.

[JMeter script image][1]

Comment: You somehow messed up your JMeter image

Answer (score 0):

Use [Parallel Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter#Sampler), the URLs can be added dynamically via [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using the following code snippet:

```
sampler.addURL('your-first-url')
sampler.addURL('your-second-url')
```

If you want to mimic browser-like behaviour you need to put the Parallel Sampler under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set the number of loops to the number of your URLs / 6